# Find files in different directories and operate on the filenames

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
$ ls /tmp/foo/
file1.txt  file2.txt
$ ls /tmp/bar/
file20.txt
$ ls /tmp/foo/file*.txt | grep -o -E '[0-9]+'  | sort -n | paste -s -d,
1,2
```

How to fetch the number in the filename from both the directories? in the above example, I need to get `1,2,20`, its in bash shell.

UPDATE:

```
$ ls /tmp/foo/file*.txt /tmp/bar/file*.txt /tmp/jaz99/file*.txt /tmp/nah/file*.txt | grep -o -E '[0-9]+'  | sort -n | paste -s -d,
ls: cannot access /tmp/nah/file*.txt: No such file or directory
1,2,20,30,99
```

in this case, it should not print 99 (as its not matched by *), and should not print the error if file not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get this done using a loop with output of `find`:

```
s=

# run a loop using find command in a process substitution
while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do
   file="${file##*/}"      # strip down all directory paths
   s+="${file//[!0-9]/},"  # remove all non-numeric characters and append comma
done < <(find /tmp/{foo,bar,nah,jaz99} -name '*.txt' -print0 2>/dev/null)

echo "${s%,}"              # remove last comma from string
```

**Output**

```
1,2,20,30
```

Comment: Please see the UPDATE section I added, with the example give under UPDATE, it gives `2,1,20,9930`, Thanks for showing me the find command, but `foo` and `bar` may not be be be under same parent dir, for example, it can be `/tmp/foo` and `/local/bar`

Comment: sorry, I tried `find {/tmp/foo,/tmp/bar,/tmp/nah,/tmp/jaz99} -name '*.txt' -printf "%f" 2>/dev/null` didn't work with your piece of code, works fine if I run it alone, (I didn't understand your last statement `echo "$file";` )

Comment: Ran `$ s=; while IFS= read -d '' -r file; do echo "$file"; s+="${file//[!0-9]/},"; done < <(find {/tmp/foo,/tmp/bar,/tmp/nah,/tmp/jaz99} -name '*.txt' -print0); echo "${s%,}" ` OUTPUT::: 
`find: /tmp/nah: No such file or directory
/tmp/foo/file2.txt
/tmp/foo/file1.txt
/tmp/bar/file20.txt
/tmp/jaz99/file30.txt
2,1,20,9930`

Comment: perfect, thanks a lot, you mind explaining the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this. Use arrays. No need to use external tools like sed or awk or find.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a a=()

for f in /tmp/{foo,bar,nah}/file*.txt; do
  [[ $f =~ .*file([0-9]+).* ]]
  a+=( ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} )
done

IFS=,
echo "${a[*]}"
```

The `[[...]]` expression populates the `$BASH_REMATCH` array with regex components. You can use that to extract the numbers and place them in a new temporary array, which you can express with comma separators using `$IFS`.

Results:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/foo /tmp/bar
$ touch /tmp/foo/file{1,2}.txt /tmp/bar/file20.txt
$ ./doit
1,2,20
```